# JAXb (version 2.2.8) marshalls gmonth in wrong format

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

The xsd file contains the following:

```
<xsd:attribute name="month" type="xsd:gMonth" use="optional"/>
```

and I try to marshall a valid XML:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setSchema(schema);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(cv, outWriter);

StringBuffer sb = ((StringWriter) outWriter).getBuffer(); 
xml = sb.toString();
```

the resulting String (xml) contains: `month="--03--"` instead of `month="--03"`.

My pom.xml dependency for jaxb is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-b01</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is this related to this issue? https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-643 It should have been resolved in 2.2.8. How can I get a proper value for the gmonth?

Comment: Did you check with recent releases than this one?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same problem. Most recent release that does not break build is: <version>2.2-promoted-b11</version>

Comment: Please post this as an answer and accept it. so, others will get benefited when they come across!

Comment: The build does not break with version b11 but the marshalling error is still there. So, the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I' sorry, Create a bug on it

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to set up FINE logging to jaxb-impl and trying to set up the

```
 jaxb.ri.useOldGmonthMapping
```

environement variable.
You should have the log line describe [here](http://code.ohloh.net/?s=%22USE_OLD_GMONTH_MAPPING%22&fp=1219&mp=&projSelected=true) because it's a a possibility that for a specific runtime deployment, you're really using the 2.2.8-b01 jaxb version.

Comment: Set up the "jaxb.ri.useOldGmonthMapping" system property with what value (use System.setProperty(..., ...), right?) ?